# Excel - How to connect to another Excel file?

Tags: excel, database, connection, powerquery

I have a big spreadsheet(Excel file A) which will be updated every month. Also, I created a parametric search in another Excel file(file B) which can pull data from Excel file A. Therefore, Once I send my parametric search Excel file B to my colleagues, they can always pull the fresh data without updating file B (I would need to update file A monthly to keep data fresh)

I tried to connect data by using Microsoft Query/web data. However, I noticed that if I use web data, the source link changes everytime I update the File A. Therefore, the file B connection won't work.

(I uploaded the file A to JIRA as an attachment. I tried to upload to Sharepoint, but Excel does not recognize Excel file on Sharepoint as an Excel file, it recognize as a html file. Therefore, I gave up using sharepoint)

Is there a better way to achieve what I have described above?
[image]
Thanks,
Jennifer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using SharePoint, choose From File > From SharePoint folder and input the root URL (e.g. https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/workspacename/).

[image: SharePoint Connector]

This should give you a dialog box like this once you've logged in:

[image: SharePoint Workspace]

Click on Edit to open the query editor.

[image]

You likely only want one particular file in there, so click on `Binary` in the row that corresponds to the File A that you should have already uploaded to that space. This will import the Excel file.

Click to expand the `Table` in the row that corresponds to the table that you want to import. This should be the table you keep up to date that gets loaded in.

Comment: Hello Alexis, if I send this excel file to others, does the connection still work?

Comment: In general, no. It would work if File A were located on a shared drive, for example.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any other way to do it? I need to send the Excel file B to my colleagues all over the world...

Comment: Do you guys already use a shared document system like Dropbox or Google Drive?

Comment: We use SharePoint. But I can create a test public account. Is it gonna work?

Comment: As long as you all have a SharePoint site you can all log into, I think you're good. See my edited answer.